# Express Session - Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'user')

Tags: typescript, express, graphql, express-session

I have a problem. While setting up the session in Express and GraphQL.

Config:

```
  app.use(
    session({
      name: "user",
      secret:
        "test",
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        secure: false,
        expires: 60 * 60 * 10000,
      },
    })
  )
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      credentials: true,
    })
  )
  app.use(express.json())
  app.use(cookieParser())
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

GraphQL route(How I get req as a parameter):

```
    graphqlHTTP({
      schema,
      graphiql: true,
      context: (req: any) => ({
        ...req,
      }),
    })
```

How I define a session:

```
      const getId = await Users.findOne({ user_email: email })

      const ID = getId?.user_id

      req.session.user = ID

      console.log("ee " + req.session.user)
```

Check if session is there:

```
    try {
      if (req.session.user) {
        return {
          success: true,
          user_id: req.session.user,
        }
      } else {
        return { success: false }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
```

And it returns `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'user')`
What is the problem?
Is it that, how I get req as a parameter, or anything else?